# no kind "Cluster" is registered for version "v1"

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kops

I'm quite new to kubernetes, and I'm trying to deploy a docker container to kubernetes.  I already have a docker container running on AWS.  I am trying to deploy the yml file through the following command:

```
kops create -f deployment.yml --state=s3://mybucket
```

However whenever I try to deploy my yml file, I get a message saying:

```
 error parsing file "deployment.yml": no kind "Cluster" is registered for version "v1"
```

My yml file looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Cluster 
metadata:
name: containers

spec:
containers:
- name: container
  image: [idnumber].dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/myfirstcontainer
  ports:
    - containerPort: 3000
```

Grateful for any help!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no `kind: Cluster` in kubernetes API v1.

You should use `kind: Pod` if you want to run only one pod or use [deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/), if you want to create controller which manages your pod:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2 # for versions before 1.8.0 use apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
```

Also, you have some issues with formatting in your `deployment.yml` file.

The final `deployment.yml` should be for pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: containers
spec:
  containers:
  - name: container
    image: [idnumber].dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/myfirstcontainer
    ports:
      - containerPort: 3000
```

or for deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1 # for versions starting from 1.8.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: containers
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: some_app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: some_app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: container
        image: [idnumber].dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/myfirstcontainer 
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help- I've tried that and I get the same error message!